# What should be cleared in componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, garbage-collection

I read that any variable declared in a `function` will be destroyed automatically after the `function` is destroyed, but the React document says that I should clear invalid timers, network requests, dom element created in `componentDidMount`, but since React component it self is a `Class`, why should I clear the variable in it if it will be destroyed? or will a `Class` will be destroyed like a `function` or not?

And most important, should I also clear all the `this.foo` `this.bar` that I declared in the constructor and the methods also the `this.state` by re-assign them to `null` too?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not clear the variables, you should clear the resources that you allocated.

Comment: No, you should only clear the special things that you created in `componentDidMount` - you don't need to do anything to the properties created in the constructor.

Comment: Can you point me to the doc ?

Comment: @Panther https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

Comment: How do you destroy the component instance?

Comment: @zero_cool I think it will automatically be destroyed when its life circle ends.